# Download .aspx file from WebClient object

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to download a ".aspx" file from the web server using a WebClient object and save it to the file system, but it raises an exception of "HTTP 500 Internal Error", I think becuase the server tries to render the html and send the content of the same rather than the file itself.

```
var objWebClient = new WebClient();    
var remoteUrl = "someserverURL" + "default.aspx";
objWebClient.DownloadFile(remoteUrl, localPathToSave);
```

Tried adding HTTP headers but I think they might not be of use with request object being from a desktop system and not a browser, have set the server, to serve all content in "application/octet-stream" format.

Comment: When you browse directly to that file using a real browser what you see? Does the page require authentication?

Comment: @ShadowWizard sorry forgot to mention it downloads all the other file types viz ".txt, .gif,.jpg" etc.No the page doesn't require the authentication. The browser based request also server the Error page "HTTP 500 Internal Error"

Comment: So this means there is error in the page, what exactly you want to download? You can't "download" the source code, it's hacking.

Comment: I want to download the page as a content rather than render it, the page doesn't belong to a website, its a simple and lonely ".aspx" page, which needs to be downloaded by the application.

Comment: Like I said and the answer says as well, you can't do that. Files with `.aspx` extension are being rendered by a server and you can't see the source code in them unless you have direct connection to the web server in which case you need to read it like a text file.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this.

If the web server is set up correctly, it will not allow you to directly download an aspx file.

The reason it downloads all your other files like jpegs and text files is because the web server will happily serve these file types and allow them to be downloaded.

If what you are attempting to do was possible then anyone would be able to download the aspx source files for any .net site, which would be hugely insecure.

What you could do is to get the rendered html content from the .aspx page and save that.

```
var webClient = new WebClient();    
var remoteUrl = "someserverURL" + "default.aspx";
byte[] data = webClient.DownloadData(remoteUrl); 
var utf8Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(); 
var html = utf8Encoding.GetString(data);

//now you could save the html to a file
```

Comment: I think you are correct, but the page on the server is a just a page (another content to download and not part of a website), I believe hnece the suggested code sample didn't work, it still throws the same error "HTTP 500 Internal Error"

Comment: Can you view the rendered html of http://someserverUrl/default.aspx in a web browser? if you can, then you wont be able to download it in the way you are trying.

Comment: Assuming that your webserver is iis, if you have set up asp.net then iis will not allow downloading .aspx files, even if the page isn't part of the website.

Comment: Yes, the web server is IIS, and I have removed the handlers serving the ".aspx" from its mapping, also after doing so I was able to download the file.